# Stuck Connecting PHP to JQuery to HTML/CSS – Displaying Social Share Numbers

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a custom social shares widget for my page.

I want it to display the number of shares on Twitter and Facebook for each wordpress post on my site.

I have some code that seems like it should work... but something isn't working. The  tags aren't being populated. Any pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated.

**PHP**

```
 <?php
 function get_likes($url) {
     $json_string = file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=' . $url . '&format=json');
     $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
     if(isset($json[0]['total_count'])){
        return intval( $json[0]['total_count'] );
     } else { return 0;}
 }

 function get_tweets($url) {
     $json_string = file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $url);
     $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
     if(isset($json['count'])){
         return intval( $json['count'] );
     } else {return 0;}
 }

     $thisUrl=$_GET["thisurl"];

     $data = "{";
     $data .= '"facebook": '. json_encode(get_likes($thisUrl)) . ", ";
     $data .= '"twitter": ' . json_encode(get_tweets($thisUrl)) . "} ";

     header('Content-Type: application/json');
     echo $data;
 ?>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function get_social_counts() {
   var thisUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'http://localhost:8888/straightcanna/get_social_counts.php?thisurl='+thisUrl,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data){
       $('.twitter span').html(data.twitter);
       $('.facebook span').html(data.facebook);
     }
   });
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
   get_social_counts();
   UTIL.loadEvents();
 });
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="share-holder">
       <ul class="social-shares">
         <li><a class="post-share facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&amp;t=<?php the_title(); ?>" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=400,width=750');return false;"><i class="icon-facebook"></i> <span></span></a></li>

         <li><a class="post-share twitter" href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?> via @straightcanna" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=400,width=750');return false;"><i class="icon-twitter"></i> <span></span></a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: you are testing it on localhost? maybe that's the problem.. it will return 0 every time..

Comment: @MateiMihai Ah yes, I am. But then shouldn't there be a "0" between the <span> tags? There's nothing right now.

Comment: what happens if you use the full url to your live site when testing locally?

Comment: @RamRaider Do you mean changing the 'url' in the javascript to a live site? I tried that, and it doesn't make any difference on the local version.

Comment: The php functions return the expected data when I tested them locally using the url for a particular website. The only thing I didn't check was using your jQuery function ( don't use jQuery ) ~ but because you are testing on your local machine ( I presume ) the value of `thisUrl` within the js function points to your localmachine

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks. Okay, I just tried changing the "thisUrl" variable to a link I know has a bunch of social shares... still nothing. Seems like my Javascript isn't working... do you know how I can see if it's being called or not?

Comment: Generally you should use the console ( most modern browsers have aconsole ) and then look for the GET request. Try putting `console.log( 'message' )` statements in your js code - or even using `alert('message')`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the PHP code to:

```
function get_likes($url) {
     $json_string = file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=' . $url . '&format=json');
     $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
     if(isset($json[0]['total_count'])){
        return intval($json[0]['total_count']);
     } 
     return 0;
 }

 function get_tweets($url) {
     $json_string = file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $url);
     $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
     if(isset($json['count'])){
         return intval($json['count']);
     }
     return 0;
 }

 echo json_encode(array(
     'facebook' => get_likes($_GET["thisurl"]),
     'twitter'  => get_tweets($_GET["thisurl"])
 ));
```

Also, use firebug to see if the request is done properly to the PHP file. You can use an absolute path to the file instead of the full URL. I don't think the current method is not working but you may check this as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried to put it into the PHP and it didn't make any difference. I tried Googling how to see php requests in Firebug and I'm not sure what's right. Is it in the console?